# Issue with Path Aliasing using "imports" in package.json - Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, package.json

I am facing difficulties implementing path aliasing using the imports field in the package.json file. Despite my efforts, I keep encountering the following error:

```
Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module 'C:\server-ts\src\messages\messages.router' imported from C:\server-ts\dist\index.js
```

directory structure

```
|   .env
|   .eslintignore
|   .eslintrc.js
|   .prettierrc.js
|   package-lock.json
|   package.json
|   tree.txt
|   tsconfig.json
|   
+---dist
|   |   index.js
|   |   index.js.map
|   |   
|   +---messages
|   |       messages.router.js
|   |       messages.router.js.map
|   |       messages.service.js
|   |       messages.service.js.map
|   |       
|   \---middleware
|           auth0.middleware.js
|           auth0.middleware.js.map
|           
+---node_modules
|           
\---src
    |   index.ts
    |   
    +---messages
    |       messages.router.ts
    |       messages.service.ts
    |       
    +---middleware
    |       auth0.middleware.ts
    |       
    \---types
            process-env.d.ts
```

package.json

```json
{
...
  "main": "src/index.ts",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsx src/index.ts",
    "dev": "tsx watch src",
        "start-node": "node dist/index.js",
    "lint": "eslint src/**/*.ts --fix",
    "build": "tsc"
  },
    "imports": {
    "##/*": "./src/*"
    },
...
}
```

tsconfig.json

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "lib": ["ES2023"],
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "##/*": ["./src/*"]
    },
    "outDir": "dist/",
    "removeComments": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  }
}
```

index.ts

```ts
...
import { messagesRouter } from '##/messages/messages.router';
...
```

- I have ensured that my TypeScript compiler version is compatible with the ECMAScript module system.
- The baseUrl and paths configurations in tsconfig.json are set up correctly, as far as I can tell.
- The paths seem correct, but the runtime is unable to locate the module.

What could be causing the "Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]" when trying to use path aliases with the imports field in package.json? Any suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

edit:
I am using [tsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsx) to run my development server that supports typescript and aliasing out of box but the while building the project by following this [github issue](https://github.com/ilearnio/module-alias/issues/113) it doesn't seems to work.

Comment: Node.js doesn't support base URLs. Those configuration options are typically used with base URL supporting tools like webpack and systemjs

Comment: @AluanHaddad, The dev environment with path aliasing seems to work fine with [tsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsx). I was trying to build the project and check if the aliasing works, I tried to work with [module-alias](https://www.npmjs.com/package/module-alias) before but that doesn't seem to work whatsoever so went with import mapping after this seeing this [github issue](https://github.com/ilearnio/module-alias/issues/113)

Comment: I see. You should add that info to the question because you're using a custom loader which is highly relevant. Looking closer at the error message, is it possible that you're missing the file extension in the module specifier?

Comment: @AluanHaddad In the error message I can see that it is looking for the file inside the src folder that has the TS file, so if I add ts extension to the module import will node be able to run it? should I change the ` "##/*": "./src/*"` to ` "##/*": "./dist/*"` so that it looks inside the dist folder after the bundling is done and I am running using node.

Comment: @AluanHaddad, It worked. Added `.js` extension to all the module imports and changed the imports to `"##/*: "./dist/*"`. Both Dev and build is working fine with these changes. Wanted to know is there any way I can omit the extension or I have to add `.js` after every file import?